# C# continuous socket listening

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to setup a server that continuously reads the strings that come throught a port.
I have come up to some piece of code but it will only read one string and then stop.
How can I modify it so that it continously reads the strings that come to that port and puts them into the textbox?

I have tried putting a "while(true)" but that would hung up my form.I am currently researching on how to make the socket listening in a backgroundWorker or Thread.

```
public void start_server()
    {
            _server_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _server_socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234));
            _server_socket.Listen(0);
            _server_socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
    }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
            _client_socket = _server_socket.EndAccept(AR);
            _buffer = new byte[_client_socket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                _client_socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_buffer);
            write(text);
    }

    private void write(string text)
    {
        MethodInvoker invoker = new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                textBox1.Text =textBox1.Text+text;
            });
        this.Invoke(invoker);
    }
```

Comment: You need to start receiving again in your `ReceiveCallback` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to restart receiving after receiving the first part by calling `BeginReceive` again.
Additionally you are also missing `EndReceive` and therefore

- have no error handling
- can not discover whether the remote side closed.
- don't know how many bytes you really received (can be less than `_buffer.Length`).

It should look like this:

```
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
        try
        {
            int bytesTransferred = resultState.Socket.EndReceive(ar);                    
            if (bytesTransferred == 0) return; // Closed
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_buffer, 0, bytesTransferred);
            write(text);

            // Read more
            _client_socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Error handling                  
        }

}
```

Comment: I would use two separate try/catch to guarantee that the next `BeginReceive()` is being called even if the `EndReceive` or buffer processing fails.

Comment: I thought about it, but it depends on your intention ;) If the `EndReceive` fails the socket is most likely closed or in an errorenous state and the next receive will fail too. So you would probably build an endless loop of failing calls. And `GetString` and `write` in this example should not throw anything.

Comment: working with the incoming data should not break the receive cycle